# Zotero: referencing multi-word organisations like "World Bank" so that it's not, "Bank, World"

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I'm using Zotero to manage references, and I've manually inputed a reference to:

```
World Bank. 2019. "World Development Indicators." URL: http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/world-development-indicators
```

So under author, I typed:

```
Author: World Bank
```

[all in the `last name` field].

When I compile my bibliography, this means that I'm getting the reference as:

```
Bank. 2019. “World Development Indicators.” http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/world-development-indicators.
```

Is there a way that I can enter a multi-word organisation as an author, and still get my desired output of:

```
World Bank. 2019. "World Development Indicators." URL: http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/world-development-indicators
```

Comment: The World Bank is the publisher, not the author.  Authors are people.

Comment: In my discipline, and in the journals that I publish in, for the purpose of referencing, authors are not limited to people at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/3275/entering-corporate-authors

There's a tiny box to the right of the author names, that if you click on, you can change the setting to a full name.